# Are exceptions thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception, thread-safety

I wonder what happens if I catch an exception and pass it to some other threads.

```
try
{
  //...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    int currIndex = i;
    Task.Run(() => e.Data[currIndex] = currIndex);
  }

  throw;
}
```

Given these other threads alter the contents of the exception's `Data` property (that holds an internal dictionary, see [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/listdictionaryinternal.cs)), will the `Data`dictionary get corrupted?

Looking into the source code of `Exception` reveals that this dictionary is not thread-safe.

If my suspicion is true, what are the consequences? I would think that you should never alter the contents of the `Data` property after throwing the exception, right?

Comment: An exception should be a snapshot of information at the point of the problem. However, having said that, I'm quite a bit of a stickler for documentation and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx) states: *Any public static ( Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe.* **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.** so I would have to say **No**.

Comment: That isn't to say that bits and pieces of an exception won't be safe if you actually do share the exception across threads, but the object in its entirety is not.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I share your opinion. But I see some people commending to enhance exceptions with additional context in the call chain (catch-block chain) by writing it into the `Data` dictionary. But I suspect this will only work if the exception is never shared between threads.

Comment: The sample makes little sense - you might trip another error while those 100 Tasks fight it out. But you don't use the exception afterwards so the effects will likely go unnoticed.

Comment: There is no real use case for this - maybe you pass it to another thread for logging but that should always treat it as immutable.

Comment: @bommelding I forgot to rethrow the exception in the catch-block - corrected. A use case is to add more context in surrounding catch-blocks of the call chain. But even if the 100 started tasks only *read* the `Data` dictionary (or a "Log Task" evaluating the exception, as you mentioned), this is not thread-safe.

Comment: You have to think of thread-safety in a piece of code like hollowness in a solid brick. Yes, a single brick is solid, but it's not hard to construct something with a number of solid bricks that is hollow. Just because all of the elements in a piece of code are thread-safe it doesn't make the code thread-safe.

Comment: There exist many examples at Stackoverflow and Codeproject, where people catch an (already in-flight) exception an add stuff to the `Data` dictionary; it seems to be a common practice. Let me summarize: **as long as an exception flows from the point where it is raised through different catch-blocks without handing it over to code which pushes it into another thread, then we are safe to add context to `Data`**. As soon as we leave this linear chain of catch-blocks by passing the exception to "unknown and potentially multi-threaded code" outside of this block, we should not touch `Data` anymore.

Comment: @bommelding In some context where async/await is used, I recently stumbled across a piece of code where an exception is caught and handed over to code that is not awaited. Immediately I thought: "Is this a good idea?" And my answer was "No!". Instead the piece of data that the other code/task needs from the exception (e.g. the exception type, the message, maybe a clone of the `Data` dictionary) should be handed over, not the complete exception. **I think that some people are not aware of the fact that an exception is not thread-safe, especially when messing around with the `Data` property.**